# Scrolling content in a div when it's passed

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, viewport

Trying to accomplish something like on this website:

http://www.strangelove.nl/cases/kpmg-meijburg

The part where the responsive design is showcased, the image inside the devices start to scroll when a visitor scrolls past that point. I've tried to replicate it and I see a .js in the footer which is probably contributing. For now I have the css and html working on my test page.

Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: maybe post some code on what you worked on or have problems with, a code snippet or a js fiddle goes a long way

Answer (score 0):

Strangelove is using their own Kubrick-js, which is available here: [Kubrick-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kubrick-js)

If you just want to have the 'images scrolling inside of frame while scrolling by'-effect, you can do it like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var animStart = 0, // the point where the animation starts
        animEnd = 500, // the point, where the animation ends
        scrollStartPos = 0, // the position your inside scrolling element starts
        scrollEndPos = -300, // the position your inside scrolling element should end
        winPosY = window.pageYOffset, // the scroll distance from top of document
        scrollElement = $('.picture'); // the element to scroll

    if(winPosY > animStart && winPosY < animEnd) {
        // how far through the animation are we?
        var howFar = (winPosY - animStart) / (animEnd - animStart),
            scrollPos = Math.round(scrollStartPos + howFar * (scrollEndPos - scrollStartPos));

        scrollElement.css('top', scrollPos + 'px');

        $('.show-stats').html('How far: ' + howFar + '<br>scroll Position: ' + scrollPos);
    }
});
```

Here is a fiddle for it: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gy72prp5/)

hope that helps.